# I want to verify if the word "anything" is in bold or not

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

The website is [enter link description here](http://ec2-54-90-154-147.compute-1.amazonaws.com/)

When you will go down you will find some POSTS, so I want to verify if "anything" written in it is in bold or not using Selenium and preferably Python!

The issue I am facing is since the whole text is not in BOLD therefore when I am using property

```
element1= driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='post-2662']/div/p")

a=element1.value_of_css_property('font-weight')
```

it gives me 400, however, I just want to find if "Anything" is in bold and if "Anything" is in bold then we can search it separately as well since it is inside a  tag but if "anything" is not in bold then it cannot be searched separately.

Complete scenario is like this:

*Given a user is logged in

When they add a blog with
Title: “This is a blog by a test_user”
Content “Test user likes to blog. The content of the blog can be **anything**.”

Then viewing the blog should show the “anything” in bold*

Comment: Looks like second is a really long sentence. Please help us with breaking it into several.

Comment: can you tokenize by whitespace, and then check if a token is anything, and also if it's bold?

Comment: I usually use tools in combination. Selenium will help you click on things, but you might find passing driver.page_source through the lxml parser will help you *walk the dom tree* easier than Selenium can. This way you can find out whether the previous element is a <strong> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your xpath will be something like this

```
"//article[1]/div/p[contains(b/text(), 'anything')]"
```

Comment: Yeah it works but I want to verify just if the top post contains "anything" in bold, can you help me out with that please?

Comment: Complete scenario is like this:  _Given a user is logged in
When they add a blog with
Title: “This is a blog by a test_user”
Content “Test user likes to blog. The content of the blog can be anything.”
Then viewing the blog should show the “anything” in bold_

Comment: @Sammy You can add [1] at the end of your xpath to get the first occurence of <b>anything</b>, but I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for. "(//article/div/p[contains(b/text(), 'anything')])[1]"

Comment: yeah that is fine, but I am looking for the top post only if it has "anything" in bold, that(your above comment) will search in the whole DOM and will give the first <b> tag, so it will automatically turn out to be true

Comment: @Sammy Then check for the first article node. Like this  "//article[1]/div/p[contains(b/text(), 'anything')]"

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your logic, but you can simply check whether paragraph contains bold `"Anything"` as below:

```
element1= driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='post-2662']/div/p")
try:
    element1.find_element_by_xpath(".//b[.='anything']")
except:
    print("No bold 'Anything' found")
```

Comment: I tried this but it actually prints the above print statement even when "anything" was in bold. @Andersson

Comment: Oh, yeah :) Wrong case. Try with `element1.find_element_by_xpath(".//b[.='anything']")`

Answer (score 0):

I would take a little different approach. When I approach problems like this I try to think of general (reusable) solutions. In this case (from what I've gathered from your question and comments) you want to find out if certain text is bold in a given blog post. Using XPath you can specify which blog post you want to examine, pull the text inside of `B` (bold) and compare it to what you expect. The XPath looks like

```
//article[1]//p/b
```

where 1 is the index of the blog post you want to search. This will find a `B` tag inside the text of blog post #1, if it exists. So, given this XPath... we will want to determine whether this element exists (anything is bold in that post) and if so get the text from it and compare it to "anything". I would wrap this all in a function to make it reusable

```
def is_text_bold_in_post(post_index, search_string):
    for bold in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article[" + post_index + "]//p/b")
        if search_string in bold.text
            # search string found
            return true
    # not found
    return false
```